# Vue.js 2-way data bind only working one way

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following element:

```
<input type="text" v-model="selectedPost.title" v-bind:value="selectedPost.title">
```

and I have the following Vue.js app:

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { 
          selectedPost: {} 
        }
});
```

When I type something on the input, the Vue model is updated, I can see it unning this on my browser console:

```
vueapp.$data.selectedPost.title
```

Returns the value typed in the textbox. All good.

But.. when I do this:

```
vueapp.$data.selectedPost.title = "changed";
```

The textbox does not update with the assigned value.

Why? How to make it work?

This jsfiddle shows the issue happening: https://jsfiddle.net/raphadko/3fLvfea2/

Comment: Could you create a complete script example so it is easier for us to debug?

Comment: Not able to reproduce this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/oa0o3rf2/

Comment: updated with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is because [Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) properties added to objects *after* the Vue has been initialized unless you add them using [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set). In this case, just initialize the title property.

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { 
          selectedPost: {title:''} 
        }
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fLvfea2/1/).

Comment: Would that be the same for sub-sub-objects? What if title is another object? I would have to initialize all it's properties beforehand?

Comment: @raphadko Yes, *any* object you add a property to. You don't have to initialize them, but if you don't you *need* to use the $set method I linked.